# Keep mysql connection open

Tags: mysql, tcl, eggdrop

I'm making a eggdrop tcl script to write activity of several public IRC channels to a database (over time this will be 10 to 15 channels I think). I have two options how to handle the database connection in mind.

1. An user says something -> Open a mysql connection to the database -> insert information about what the user said -> close the connection
2. Start the bot -> Open a mysql connection to the database -> Insert information when there is channel activity -> Wait for more information etc.

I think it's better to use case 1, but when there is much channel activity I think opening and closing a connection every time will cause a massive server load and slows things down drastically after a while.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the connection open just call

```
mysql::ping $dbhandle
```

from time to time.

This can be done with something like this:

```
proc keepMySqlOpen {dbhandle} {
    mysql::ping $dbhandle
    after 2000 [list keepMySqlOpen $dbhandle]
}
....
    set dbh [mysql::open ...]
    keepMySqlOpen $dbh
...
```

An other option is just to use `mysql::ping` before accessing the db, which should according to the [mysqltcl manual](http://www.xdobry.de/mysqltcl/mysqltcl.html#16) reconnect if necessary. This might be the best of both worlds (let the connection time out if there is not much activity, keep it open otherwise).